# ASP LIne 12 Error in Main LIVE Navigation!

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, include

Boss called this morning and apparently our "Live" button is not working.
http://702wedding.com/

Im using a .txt include.

Anyone see what the problem is? I am still searching myself until I come up with something.

Thanks.
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correct. It's a path problem.

The page `yoursite.com/live` is looking for `includes/post-title.txt` .

You told it to look at `includes/post-title.txt`, that is, `yoursite.com/live/includes/post-title.txt`.

But it really lives here `yoursite.com/includes/post-title.txt`.

Comment: OK, I fixed that, But Line 71 is messed up the same way, cant seem to figure it out. I keep showing it where it needs to go. Maybe I need to clear my browser cache. . . .

Comment: You might want to roll back your live site to the latest working version while you figure this out @_@